# How to delete all files in particular folder present in current directory sub-folders excluding a certain file?

Tags: command-line

There are lots of posts where people asking how to delete files except ones, but my question is more specific. There are several folders named `migrations` in current directory's sub-folders, which contain `__init__.py` file and some more. How to delete all files except `__init__.py` in all sub-folders named `migrations` from current folder?

UPD: And is it possible to overwrite `__init__.py` with empty file?

Folder structure:

```
├── folder_1
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
├── folder_2
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
├── folder_3
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

Comment: you mean that, if the _init_.py is outside a "migrations" folder, it can be deleted?

Comment: @Vitor please check edited post, mb there are some bad grammar in my english, but I think it makes sense.

Comment: just let us know the hierarchy of your directory structure so it will be more useful to solve your problem

Comment: @JohnAnkanna check please updated post

Comment: __init__.py are always inside "migrations", so you just loop into files. if the file is __init__.py empty it, if not delete it. Am I right?

Comment: @Vitor yes, exactly, `__init__.py` means that folder is python package. So all the `migration` folders are packages.

Comment: I'm doing it, wait

Comment: Do you want to delete the `__pycache__` directory as well, or only the files immediately in `migration` (`0001_initial.py`, in this case)?

Comment: @muru would like to delete everything except `__init__.py`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `find`:

```
find . -path '*/migrations/__init__.py' -exec truncate -s 0 {} + -o -path '*/migrations/*' -delete
```

This runs `find` in the current directory (`.`), and:

- for anything matching `migrations/__init__.py`, it will run the `truncate` command. `truncate -s 0 <file>` reduces the file to size 0 (empty);
- failing that match, for anything matching `migrations/*`, it will delete it;
- the `*` in `-path` matches `/` unlike the `*` in bash.

Example:

```
$ tree                                                                                                                                   
.
├── folder_1
│   └── migrations
│       ├── 0001_initial.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __pycache__
│           ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│           └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
├── folder_2
│   └── migrations
│       ├── 0001_initial.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __pycache__
│           ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│           └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
└── folder_3
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── migrations
        ├── 0001_initial.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── __pycache__
            ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
            └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc

9 directories, 15 files
$ find . -path '*/migrations/__init__.py' -exec truncate -s 0 {} + -o -path '*/migrations/*' -delete                
$ tree                                                                                              
.
├── folder_1
│   └── migrations
│       └── __init__.py
├── folder_2
│   └── migrations
│       └── __init__.py
└── folder_3
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── migrations
        └── __init__.py

6 directories, 6 files

$ wc -l */migrations/__init__.py
0 folder_1/migrations/__init__.py
0 folder_2/migrations/__init__.py
0 folder_3/migrations/__init__.py
0 total
```

Comment: Thanks, new command for me `truncate`.

Comment: +1 Pro find usage, does `-o` only operate on anything which isn't matched the first expression? I can only find it in the examples section of the man page.

Comment: @Arronical yes, it's an OR. You can find it in the `OPERATORS` section of [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) (right above `STANDARDS CONFORMANCE`). It's also part of POSIX.

Comment: Cheer @muru, my lazy eyes struck again!

Answer (score 2):

Create a .py file, edit the path (directory that you will work), and compile it (python3).

- code: delete all files on 'path' except 'target_file' inside 'target_folder', that are just clear(empty).

```py
import os, sys
path='/home/vitor/Desktop/teste/'
target_folder='migrations'
target_file='__init__.py'

for directory, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files:
        folder_name=os.path.split(os.path.abspath(directory))[-1]
        if(folder_name==target_folder and file_name==target_file):
            open(directory+'/'+file_name, 'w').close()
        else:
            os.remove(directory+'/'+file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I'd like to have command line solution. I have already script in python which does this function, I upvoted your answer. Thanks for your effort.
https://gist.github.com/MichaelPavlov/a1394fca9a4a0228a2dcc12427121f5a

Comment: @МихаилПавлов just call the script from the command line? You can even pass command line arguments as target folder and target file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler command. I know some one already answered the question, but these commands should be simpler and unique. Try them to see if they work.

To remove every subfolder and file except `__init__.py` and displays which files have been deleted, try the following commands:

```
rm -rfv ./*/migrations/!(__init__.py)
```

To make a empty file, just add the following command in addition:

```
> ./*/migrations/__init__.py
```

The above command is just like writing empty data to a file like as follows:

```
/dev/null > ./*/migrations/__init__.py
```

## Note

All these commands execute from current directory `.`

## Precaution

Please make a backup before you try any of the commands. No one is 100% perfect in this world.

Comment: Your first command is almost certainly using an extended glob. Zsh?